# Stack Corruption, have no idea what's causing it

Tags: c++, corruption

So, just to have a little something to do, I worked on implementing the AES algorithm in C++. It compiles and links perfectly fine. The minute I run it though, VS2015 reports that the stack is corrupted around variable "temp". It show me exactly where it's happening, but I don't see anything funky in that code:

```
void rotWord(Word &it)
{
    Word temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        temp[(i - 1) % 4] = it[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        it[i] = temp[i];
}
```

By the way, `Word` is declared as `typedef Byte Word[4]`, where `Byte` is just a class. Any idea what's causing the stack corruption here? I can post the full source if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    temp[(i - 1) % 4] = it[i];
```

Guess what (0-1) % 4 is?

It's -1.

On the first iteration of the loop, with `i` being 0, this will evaluate to:

```
temp[-1]=it[0];
```

Change this to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    temp[(i + 3) % 4] = it[i];
```

Comment: Even more troubling, in C standards prior to 2011, the sign or `(-1) % 4` is implementation-defined. So it *might* be -1, but not necessarily. (Your fix is good.)

Comment: Fixed the issue. Now I need to look through my code to fix, though.  I think I did that in several other places...

Comment: @DanRoche this is a C++ question

Answer (score 1):

```
temp[(i - 1) % 4] = it[i];
```

For `i = 0`

```
temp[((0 - 1) % 4]
temp[(-1) % 4]
temp[-1]
```

Which is undefined behavior.